# Warning 8618 en control razor en un Parametro en cascada (CascadingParameter)

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

Dentro de un control, recibo por parámetro en cascada el valor del estado de autenticación.

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
```

Sin embargo, esta línea de código causa que se levante el warning:

> El elemento propiedad "authenticationStateTask" que no acepta valores
> NULL debe contener un valor distinto de NULL al salir del constructor.
> Considere la posibilidad de declarar el elemento propiedad como que
> admite un valor NULL.

El mismo, tampoco puede ser null. Entonces, como se hace para evitar este warning diciéndole a blazor que realmente no puede ser nulo, porque esto es inyectado por el padre de este control?

Answer (score 1):

Este error puede resolverse haciendo dos cosas.

Primero, hay que agregar el tipo de valor por defecto. Para ello, usamos el operador [`default`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default)

Y luego, agregamos el operador unario [`! (null forgiven)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Entonces, podemos producir la siguiente linea, que ya no genera el warning:

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; } = default!;
```

Esta respuesta esta inspirada en la brindada a la misma pregunta en [SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73465000/73749)